# how to append multiple items to a list in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a list that i want to append multiple items to it using python when i try to add the system crash and display the below error:

I already tried `append()` function  `extend()` function the same crash and error.

> ---
>
> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-24-1e9480855366> in <module>
>     121
>     122 
> --> 123     joineddd.extend(link,jobdesc,alldd)
>     124 
>     125 
>
> TypeError: extend() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
> ```

## code:

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get("https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/").content,
    "lxml"
)

links = []
for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
    if a['href'] not in links:
        links.append("https://www.bayt.com"+ a['href'])

joineddd = []

for link in links:
    print(link)
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
    jobdesc=s.select_one("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] p")
    print(jobdesc.text)
    alldt = [dt.text for dt in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dt")]
    dt_Job_location =              alldt[0]
    dt_Job_Company_Industry =      alldt[1]
    dt_Job_Company_Type =          alldt[2]
    if len(alldt[3])>0:
        dt_Job_Job_Role =              alldt[3]
    elif len(dt_Job_Employment_Type)>0:
        dt_Job_Employment_Type =       alldt[4]
    
    alldd = [dd.text for dd in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dd")]
    dd_job_location =             alldd[0]
    dd_job_Company_Industry =     alldd[1]
    dd_job_Company_Type =         alldd[2]
    if len(alldd[3])>0:
        dd_job_Job_Role =             alldd[3]
    elif len(dd_job_Employment_Type)>0:
        dd_job_Employment_Type =      alldd[4]
    
    print(f"{dt_Job_location}:{dd_job_location}\n{dt_Job_Company_Industry}:{dd_job_Company_Industry}\n\n")
    
    print("-" * 80) 


    
    joineddd.extend(link,jobdesc,alldd)
```

expected result :

```
[link,description,location,Company_Industry,Company_Type,Job_Role,Employment_Type ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `list.extend` method, but use square brackets around the items like so:

```
list = [1,2,3]

list.extend([4,5])

print(list)

>> returns 1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

For Extend function you need to provide a list/touple/dict/set to add multiple items.

Like :-

```py
joineddd.extend([link,jobdesc,alldd])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get("https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/").content,
    "lxml"
)

links = []
for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
    if a['href'] not in links:
        links.append("https://www.bayt.com"+ a['href'])

joineddd = []

for link in links:
    print(link)
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
    jobdesc=s.select_one("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] p")
    print(jobdesc.text)
    alldt = [dt.text for dt in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dt")]
    dt_Job_location =              alldt[0]
    dt_Job_Company_Industry =      alldt[1]
    dt_Job_Company_Type =          alldt[2]
    if len(alldt[3])>0:
        dt_Job_Job_Role =              alldt[3]
    elif len(dt_Job_Employment_Type)>0:
        dt_Job_Employment_Type =       alldt[4]
    
    alldd = [dd.text for dd in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dd")]
    dd_job_location =             alldd[0]
    dd_job_Company_Industry =     alldd[1]
    dd_job_Company_Type =         alldd[2]
    if len(alldd[3])>0:
        dd_job_Job_Role =             alldd[3]
    elif len(dd_job_Employment_Type)>0:
        dd_job_Employment_Type =      alldd[4]
    
    print(f"{dt_Job_location}:{dd_job_location}\n{dt_Job_Company_Industry}:{dd_job_Company_Industry}\n\n")
    
    print("-" * 80) 


    
    joineddd.extend([link,jobdesc,alldd])
```

dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
array1 = ["value1", "value2"]
array2 = ["value1"]

df = dict( A = np.array(array1), B = np.array(array2 ) )

_df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df.items() ]))


print(_df)
_df.to_csv("filename.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

output:

```
        A       B
0  value1  value1
1  value2     NaN
```

Comment: how to add this list **joineddd** to a dataframe ?? where it must have 7 columns

Comment: To write to excel or csv file?

Comment: to write to a csv file note that not all  headers contains value so some records can has 1 or 2 columns as empty values